# Pagination accessibility

Tags: reactjs, pagination, navigation, accessibility

What should be `aria-label` for link with dots in it? That indicates that there are more pages in between.

Do we still need to wrap everything in `ul` with `li` or following structure is fine?

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <a href='page-1' aria-label='Goto page 1'>1</a>
  <a href='page-2' aria-label='Goto page 2'>2</a>
  <a href='page-3' aria-label='Goto page 3'>3</a>
  <a href='#' aria-label='...'>...</a>
  <a href='page-10' aria-label='Goto page 10'>10</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: What happens when you click on the "..." link?  The resulting action will determine what the label should be.  BTW, you don't need `role="navigation"` on a `<nav>` element because that's the default role.  I would still have all the links in a list because that will give the screen reader user a hint as to how many links there are.

Comment: Why did you choose to change the accessible name of the links? Is there a source that suggests so?

Comment: I recommend removing the reactjs tag, it’s irrelevant for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My following answer is theoretical and I don’t have any insights from usability testing with screen reader users!

In pagination, … serves as an ellipsis, contracting several pages, while always keeping the first and last page in the list, which communicates the total number of pages.

Sometimes, this ellipsis is a link to the adjacent page, sometimes it’s not a link, for example in the [Gov.uk Design System Pagination](https://design-system.service.gov.uk/components/pagination/#for-larger-numbers-of-pages)

That’s the biggest error in the example code: The ellipsis is linked to #. It should either not be a link at all, or be linked to the adjacent page, in this case 4.

Personally, I would recommend the link.

### ARIA labels

It’s quite repetitive to listen to “go to page” for each page. It’s no different to showing that text visually: It’s simply noise.

“Goto” is quite redundant for a link.

“Page 1” would be sufficient, as the Gov.uk navigation does it. Simply 1, 2, 3 might suffice as well. The navigation’s name should probably convey that it’s a page navigation. It's likely not the only navigation on the page, so it should have a name anyway.

> A best practice is to have the text of the label at the start of the name.

[Understanding Success Criterion 2.5.3: Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html)

```html
<nav aria-label="Results pages">
…
<a href="page-1">1</a>
```

### Conveying the total number of pages

A list should be used so that a screen reader can announce the number of links available in the navigation.

This will not correspond to the total number of pages. The ellipsis explains that visually and also to assistive technology.

In tables and grids, [`aria`rowcount` can be used to convey the total number of rows if they are not in the DOM](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-rowcount). This attribute is disputed, though, and does not exist for lists.

Since the ellipsis would be linking to page 4, it should simply labelled so.

While the fact that it will render available another range of pages might be implicit in the lack of links between 4 and 10, you could add that to the accessible name:

```html
<a href="page-4" aria-label="4…">…</a>
```

Another option is to simply not link page 4, as Gov.uk does.

```html
<li><a href="page-3">3</a></li>
<li>…</li>
<li><a href="page-10">10"</a></li>
```

### Mark the current page

A pagination should also use `aria-current` to mark the current page.

```html
<a href="page-3" aria-current="page">3</a>
```

So my total suggestion would be

```html
<nav aria-label="Results pages">
<ul>
  <li><a href="page-1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page-2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="page-3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="page-4" aria-label="4…">…</a></li>
  <li><a href="page-10">10</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

### Why contract pages?

The interest of contracting pages is based on the realisation that users’ interest declines (probably exponentially) after page 1. Users would probably rather change their search criteria or whatever brought them to the list, than proceeding to page 4. Screen real estate, especially on mobile, makes this even more interesting.

> Assuming that you can prioritize the list items, users are likely to find what they want close to the top. To focus users’ attention and improve response time, you can start by showing a fairly short list, and then offer pagination options for progressing further down the list if needed.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/item-list-view-all/

Comment: '...' won't be linking to anywhere and disabled styling is applied to it. It exists only to indicate that there are more pages in between.

Comment: It was built based on this lesson: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-a-custom-pagination-component-in-react/

Comment: You say that you don't have any practical experience with screen readers. I'm a screen reader myself and I can confirm that it's a very good answer with excellent advice, I have almost nothing to add. Just one thing: the simplest to convey the number of pages is just to write it explicitly, i.e. Page 3 of 10, 3/10, or even better with ellipsis, we implicitly know how many pages there are if you always show the link to the last page.

Comment: @Alyona thanks for sharing the lesson. It has terrible accessibility with several fundamental errors! Your example code is already way better. I’m not sure whether I understand correctly, though. How are you making sure that … is not linking anywhere? In your example, it’s still a link. Applying disabled styling would not be enough. You’d actually need to remove the `href` or the whole link together. Maybe you could update your question?

Answer (score 2):

Why is there a link on the "..." – it doesn't lead anywhere, which by itself is bad concerning semantics and accessibility...

I would make that a plain text element (`span`, or `li` if you decide to make it a list, which IMO is better), without a link